# Echoing a variable in an included php file

Tags: php, html

Okay, so let's say I have a webpage with a defined php $variable, and then I use include("variableEchoed.php), which just echos $variable.

How do I accomplish this? Simply doing what I said above doesn't work.

Again, I want to use an included php file to echo a variable onto another webpage where that variable is defined.

Comment: It should work - please post your code.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an explanation. You want help with specific code - you need to show it

Answer (score 3):

Index.php

---

```
<?php
$variable = 'test';
include('variableEchoed.php');
?>
```

variableEchoed.php

---

```
<?php
echo($variable);
?>
```

The result will be `test`.

Comment: +1 . And if echoing a variable outside function, use `global $variable` like this:  `function test() { global $variable; echo $variable; }`

Answer (score 0):

yes its easily doable.

```
$ cat 1.php 
<?
echo $x;
?>

$ cat 2.php 
<?
$x="hello world";
include("1.php");
?>

$ php 2.php 
hello world
```

Answer (score -1):

Write a function in the file to echo that `$variable.`. Call the function just after including the file.